# How do I finish this question to find the basis of the image of T?

Tags: linear-transformations

Take $T(x,y,z) = (x+2y-z,y+z,x+y-2z)$,
to get:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 \\ 
0 & 1 & \hspace{3mm} 1 \\
1 & 1 & -2 
\end{bmatrix}

We can write this in RREF as

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -3 \\ 
0 &1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

Hence, the basis for the kernel of T is [ 3 1 -1 ]. However, how do I use the RREF to find a basis for the image of T?

Comment: Could you format  your formulæ with *MathJax*? I don't understand how your matrix relates to the formula for $T(x,y,z)$.

Comment: I don't know what that is but I do now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you have show that the matrix in RREF is:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

A basis for $\operatorname{Im }(T)$ would be taking the corresponding columns containing leading ones in RREF. So, column 1 and column 2 in RREF have leading ones. Thus, the corresponding columns before implementing row operations would be $(1,0,1)^T$ and $(2,1,1)^T$. Hence, a basis for $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ would be:

$\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\
0\\
1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\
1\\
1 \end{bmatrix}$}
, and in fact it can be seen that $\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T))=2$

For $Ker(T)$,

taking $z$ as a free variable, the system yields $y=-z$ and $x=3z$. Thus, solution to $AX=0$ are $X=z(3,-1,1)^T$, and thus a basis for $\operatorname{Ker}(T)$ would be $\{\begin{bmatrix} 3\\
-1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$}, and it can be seen that $dim(Ker(T))=1$. Hence, our solution follows the Rank-Nullity Theorem:

$\operatorname{Rank}(T)$ + $\operatorname{Nullity}(T)$ = $\dim(T)$

$\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T))$ + $\dim(\operatorname{Ker}(T))$ = 3

$2 + 1 = 3$

$3 = 3$

Comment: Bernard I understand you are using your power to help me however you making edits to Mohamed's text has lead to the answer for the basis of ker(T) to now be incorrect and I can't now understand the rest, please stop for a second and review your edits if you're going to be so critical everything we do.

Comment: @murpw2011 I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you, Mohamed I understand that  pretty well, is it that (2,1,1)-3(1,0,1)=(-1,1,-2) why column 3 isn't used in the basis for the image and showuld we reduce (2,1,1) to  (1,1,0) for the basis of the image of T.

Comment: That's correct. We don't include $(-1,1,-2)^T$ because the set would then not be linearly independent and hence not a basis. Reducing it will still be a basis, yes. It's not a requirement to reduce it. Both answers work.

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let A be the matrix representing your transformation T.

The image of T is the vector space spanned by the columns of A. So our problem consist in finding a basis for the space spanned by the columns of the matrix (i.e. the *column space* of the matrix).

There are two equivalent strategies to achieve that:

1. You transpose the matrix A, reduce it to the row reduced echelon form by applying elementary operations and then the non-null rows of the matrix you obtained form a basis of the column space of A, and thus a basis of $\operatorname{im}(T)$
2. You reduce the matrix A first, then you select only the columns where pivots appear (the "pivot columns"). These columns will form a basis of the column space of A.

Here you will find a clear explanation of why this two approaches work and are equivalent: http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-CRS.html